# jQuery code won't run when index.html is opened in browser. no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just can't get a very simple toggleClass() to work and I can't figure out why. It's actually just an exercise to get started with jQuery. It works fine here as a snippet and when I enter it manually in the console just not when I open the index.html file from my computer in Chrome or Firefox. 
When I then enter the jQuery manually in the console, it works, too! The files are all linked properly, I've confirmed via alert. The div appears red and won't change colour when hovered. Any suggestions??

```js
$('.test').hover(
  function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('testhover');
});
```

```css
 .test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.testhover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: wow that's ugly as a comment. sorry. the jquery goes first. is that wrong?

Comment: Please add your full HTML code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you insert your script BEFORE the .test element. 
While the DOM loads, it first executes your script, and then adds div.test.

```
<div class="test"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this will solve it

Comment: thats is, however, only a solution for this snippet. In real life, you usually run your jQuery code upon document.ready

jQuery has a special shorthand syntax for this:

    $(function() { // run your code here  });

Comment: Thank you so much. I know, this is so so basic but obviously I did not know what to google or search for in the forums.